# How can an int be converted into an id?

Tags: ios, objective-c, int, nsarray, type-conversion

I have an array, and the contents of it are objects of type `id`, but I need to turn them into type `in`t. Is there any way I can make the array read the data as `int`s, or turn the `id` into an `int`?

```
    NSArray *array = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

    int foo = array[0];  /*Warning: Incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'int' with an expression of type 'id' */
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`componentsSeparatedByString:` docs says:

> **Return value**
>
> An `NSArray` object containing substrings from the receiver that have been divided by separator.

So your `fileContents` contains an array of `NSStrings`. `fileContents[0]` is then the first  `NSString` instance in the array. And you can convert `NSString` to `int` or preferably `NSInteger` by calling

```
[string intValue];
[string integerValue];
```

So your code should look like this (assuming array contains at least 1 object, don't forget to check this):

```
int object1 = [fileContents[0] intValue];
```

Or even better include typecasting for better code readability

```
int object1 = [(NSString *)fileContents[0] intValue];
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `intValue` to convert to `int`.

```
int object1 = [fileContents[0] intValue];
```